# Multiple Qtips on one element not working

Tags: jquery, tooltip, qtip

Building a calendar, when the user hovers over a day, I want a tool tip to show, but if the user clicks on the day, I want a separate tool tip to show up. So far, when I hover nothing happens, but when I click it works.

HTML:

```
echo "<span><a href='#' class='add_event_tooltip tooltip' title="\$list_day\">$list_day</a></span>";
```

jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!-- TOOL TIP -->
$('.tooltip').live('mouseover', function(event) {
   $(this).qtip({
      overwrite: true, 
      position: { viewport: $(window)},   
       style: {
       classes: 'ui-tooltip-shadow ui-tooltip-rounded'
      },
      show: {
         event: event.type, 
         ready: true 
      }
   }, event); 
})
</script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$('.add_event_tooltip').qtip({
        content: {
            ajax: { 
                url: 'test.html'
            },
        },
        position: {
            my: 'center', // ...at the center of the viewport
            at: 'center',
            target: $(window)
        },
        show: {
            event: 'click', // Show it on click...
            solo: true, // ...and hide all other tooltips...
            modal: true // ...and make it modal
        },
        hide: false,
        style: 'ui-tooltip-light ui-tooltip-rounded'
});
</script>
```

Is it possible that one class is over-riding the other class? Is so , how can I get this so that both tooltips will work with each other, .tooltip on mouseover, and .add_event_tool on click.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
style:"class: 'ui-tooltip-shadow ui-tooltip-rounded'"
```

It should not be classes, try chnaging it to class.

```
style:"class:'ui-tooltip-light ui-tooltip-rounded'"
```

You are missing class here, other things are just fine. try now

Comment: Sorry, but that just the style for the qtip itself, not having trouble with that.

Answer (score 0):

The solution may now have changed with the latest version of qTip2.  In order to get multiple qTips to work on the same target I had to add the overwrite:false option to the second qtip.

http://qtip2.com/options#core.overwrite